# Any differences between Lagrange polynomial on Chebyshev points and Chebyshev polynomial?

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

I have to find an approximate continuous function that passes through a number of points. Many have said that the best (for my specific problem) is to use Chebyshev polynomial decomposition. I have another solution and I want to know if there is **any real differences** in the precision (or  something else) between these two strategies:

1-I can have a Lagrange interpolation polynomial on Chebyshev extrema points.

2-I can have a Chebyshev decomposition on its extrema points.

We know that both of them are polynomials of the same order, both uses the same points, and both polynomials pass exactly through these points. As there is one unique polynomial of such type, is there any differences between these two approximations?

Comment: In theory they are the same (the existence/uniqueness of the interpolating polynomial follows from the invertibility of the so-called Vandermonde matrix). In practice the Lagrange method is not a very good way to find an interpolating polynomial.

Comment: I should say: it's a bad way to find an interpolating polynomial *in exact arithmetic* because you have to do all the work again to add a single point to the interpolation nodes. It's an especially bad way to find one in floating point arithmetic because the evaluation is not numerically stable.

Comment: @Ian: thanks for your reply. I don't need point addition and so using Lagrange is not too bad to use. about the numerically stability, I can't understand the differences between Chebyshev and Lagrange method instability manner. could you explain more about the stability problem, please?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean when you say "Chebyshev method", the Chebyshev nodes don't specify a method for computing the interpolating polynomial. The usual contrast is between Lagrange and Newton. In the Lagrange case the values of the Lagrange elements are often quite large in between the nodes. This means that you get subtraction of nearly equal numbers, which is a common cause of floating point issues. Also, the Newton method gives you the polynomial in a form suitable for use with Horner's method, which saves you floating point operations in computing the polynomial.

Comment: @Ian: I know that the Lagrange polynomial formulation is not suitable when adding points are the matter(in comparison with newton), but it is not my problem. I can decompose my problem(an ODE problem) to chebyshev space with discrete chebyshev transformation, or I can fit a polynomial of the same order from chebyshev points(cosine spaces points) and use that polynomial to solve my problem. as chebyshev transformation  causes some difficulties in boundary conditions, I wanted to know if this polynomial through these points are also OK.?

Comment: I don't know what the discrete chebyshev transformation is, sorry. I assume it is analogous to the DFT after transforming coordinates or something like that.